# What is the meaning of concircular..

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the meaning of the concircular?

It says that the any five points are pairwise nonparallel and no four of them are concircular.

Comment: I found this reference to the term concircular: "A transformation of an n-dimensional Riemannian manifold M, which transforms every geodesic circle of M into a geodesic circle, is called a concircular transformation". This term seems to be attributed to [Kentaro Yano](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pja/1195579139)

Answer (score 4):

The usual term in geometry is [**concyclic,**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concyclic_points) (much less frequently, *cocyclic*), meaning that the points lie on the same circle. That is what is intended here by the term concircular.